# Daylight Saving Time - forward or backward?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Halachically speaking, do I *have to* set my clocks forward one hour in the spring, or can I set them back one hour (this will give me two hours more in my day than everyone setting their clocks forward one hour)?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15002/5

Comment: What's with all the downvotes on these two questions??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latter course of action is not recommended. If you are two hours ahead of everyone else, then that will lead to great confusion, so that those will be "bad hours" - and we specifically pray (in Shabbos morning davening, before Kerias Hatorah) ויציל נפשותינו מן השעות הרעות, that Hashem should save our souls from the bad hours.

So the proper way is indeed to set them forward one hour. In this way, you will be קונה עולמו בשעה אחת (buying the entire world with a single hour).

Comment: No, I'd be two hours _behind_. Don't you see how great that would be?

Comment: @SethJ: then that would be even worse. Yirmiyahu (7:24) castigates those who ויהיו לאחור ולא לפנים - are behind rather than ahead.

Comment: Hmm, that's a shame.

Answer (score 4):

I have actually seen the Timexer Rebbe put his clock back by 3 hours in the spring in order to always be on time for Tisch.

Comment: How does he reconcile that with [Alex's comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15003/daylight-saving-time-forward-or-backward/15013#comment28839_15013)?