# PTIJ: Can we change the liturgy for the day before the clock change?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The well-known custom for generations in holy congregations in the United States is to conclude services on the last Shabbat that's at least 27 days before [*Tekufat Nissan*](https://www.jewfaq.org/chamah.htm) with the following formula, [in English](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36146/announcing-the-clock-change-in-english):

> Gabbai: Don't forget to set your clocks forward one hour tonight. If you show up an hour late for davening tomorrow morning and no one's here, it'll be because you forgot.
> Congregation: Ha. Ha. Ha.

A similar formula is recited on the first Shabbat that's at least 24 days after [*Tekufat Tishrei*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15169/2):

> Gabbai: Don't forget to set your clocks back one hour tonight. If you show up an hour early for davening tomorrow morning and no one's here, it'll be because you forgot.
> Congregation: Ha. Ha. Ha.

Days after the change preceding *Tekufat Nissan* in 5782, the secular authorities [took steps toward](https://thehill.com/homenews/senate/598314-senate-unanimously-approves-making-daylight-saving-time-permanent) eliminating the [traditional](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15002/is-daylight-saving-time-a-mitzvah-deoraitha-or-takkanah-derabanan) clock-changes.<sup>?</sup> Clearly, if this decree is signed and sealed, we will be forced comply and to stop changing our clocks. If everyone [did](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15003/daylight-saving-time-forward-or-backward) what was just in their own eyes, that would lead to [excessive confusion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/322/halakhic-international-date-line-issues).

Just as clearly, the changing circumstances could never justify eliminating this traditional portion of our Shabbat services. However, I'm wondering if any contemporary Rabbinic authorities<sup>!</sup> have explored making a minor change to the wording of this formula, so that we don't accidentally advise people to [violate Halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dina-dmalchusa-dina). What alterations to this announcement or to other parts of the [liturgy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69320/seeking-texts-of-all-prayers-associated-with-the-clock-change) surrounding the clock changes have rabbis proposed?

---

<sup>? How they can [exceed their authority](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100484/ptij-what-is-the-basis-for-daylight-saving-time-changes-nowadays) like that is another question.</sup>

<sup>! Naturally, those with sufficiently "broad shoulders" to even consider discussing such a change.</sup>

<sup>[^](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80329/what-are-we-supposed-to-do-about-losing-an-hour-of-purim-this-year)</sup>

---

## This question is Purim Torah and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: More importantly -- what's the *yekkish* version of this liturgy? (True story: at a German shul, the gabbai announced on Shabbos "Wednesday is December 4th, your wives all know to expect you home late.")

Comment: @Shalom My grandmother is German.  Any clocks in rooms that aren't going to be used on Shabbos get changed on Friday.  The rest get changed the minute Shabbos is over.

Comment: In the real yekkishe households, change only occurs at 2 am precisely ;-)

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok In the real yekkish households, there is no change.

Comment: That is not how we did it in Frankfurt.