# Time dilation and waiting between meat and milk

Tags: halacha, time, travel, meat-and-milk, science

Suppose Ploni eats some meat. He then gets in a spaceship and accelerates to some significant percentage of the speed of light for a short trip into outer space, and then returns home. At the time when he returns home, exactly six hours have passed from the Earth's reference frame; however, because of [time dilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/time_dilation), less than 6 hours have passed for him.

This is not an issue of who is right.  On Earth, six hours have *actually* passed, whereas for Ploni, the amount of time has *actually* been less than six hours. Now that he has returned home, may he eat something with milk?

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1208/759

Comment: my gut (ha!) reaction would be that he has to wait until HE has passed 6 hours. The origin (IIRC) has to do with the time one would wait till another meal. Just because you change the clocks forward and "lose" an hour doesn't change the biological process. Is there responsa on how to deal with the time change vis-vis halachic time periods?

Comment: I like how the time and travel tags line up right next to each other.

Comment: @Dan What about if he was on the spaceship when he ate the meat, and then he stopped, picked up a passenger, and continued going. He would pass 6 hours before the passenger would perceive him to pass 6 hours. Big maris ayin problem, no?

Comment: why is there mar'is ayin? the passenger never saw him eat before the passenger was picked up. when you see someone eating milk do you randomly assume he ate meat recently? once the passenger is picked up, they share the same time frame.

Comment: @Dan Perhaps they were video-conferencing while the space-traveler was eating meat (ignoring the fact that each would seem to be moving very slowly to the other). He then picked up the passenger and they continued on their way. 6 hours after the eating would pass for the first before it did for the second.

Comment: my physics isn't good enough to comment on the possibility to teleconferencing at the speed of light while traveling near the SOL. Either way, maybe the passenger would just assume he's Dutch. We don't generally assess someone else's practice and draw conclusions without asking. "Dan" l'chaf zchus.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12795/call-for-halachic-dateline-sources

Comment: @Daniel Stopping a spaceship traveling near the speed of light causes time dilation in and off itself - just the acceleration of stopping or starting causes time dilation. Time would slow down for the spaceship traveler (since he is the one undergoing acceleration). In fact this acceleration is the *only* reason for the time dilation - the high speed travel of the spaceship causes no net time dilation, because both the earth and the traveler see each other as traveling fast.

Comment: @ariel time dilation is a result of relative velocity (see the Wikipedia page). To both observers, the other observer's time appears to run slow.

Comment: @Daniel It's more complicated than that. Only one of the observers experiences acceleration, which changes things dramatically.

Comment: @Ariel, you are right. Acceleration does affect time dilation in some way that I no longer remember. I think the idea behind the question still stands, though.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, the question still stands, this was just a comment about the details. It's not just acceleration that causes time dilation - a gravitational field does as well (because acceleration feels *identical* to gravity). So clocks on earth tick slower than than clocks in free fall (like the space station).

Comment: @Daniel To calculate gravitational dilation (which is exactly the same thing as acceleration) imagine standing on a merry go round (carousel) and spinning. You feel a force pushing you off the carousel. This force is your acceleration. Now measure your linear velocity from the speed of the rim of the carousel (i.e. the speed as compared to the ground below you). Plug in the formula for dilation due to velocity, and you now know how much dilation acceleration causes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The short answer is no. Waiting between consuming meat and consuming dairy has nothing to do with how much time we perceive to have elapsed but with the experience of the person who consumed it. Spaceman Ploni, who decided to eat meat immediately prior to takeoff (a revolting thought), can still taste it when he returns to earth, despite the fact that his more sensible brother, who ate meat with him but who didn't board the space-ship, is now enjoying a milkshake.

Source:

- Rambam, *Hilkhot Ma'akhalot Asurot* 9:28, which gives the reason for waiting six hours as being because of food that is still between the teeth (although see the Kesef Mishna there);
- Tur, YD 89:1, which gives the reason as being because of the flavour of the meat that remains in the mouth.

Comment: That truly is a revolting thought. Especially considering the acceleration necessary to get up to a fraction of the speed of light and then back down to 0 in under 6 hours. Definitely makes more sense to be the [identical twin brother](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/twin_paradox).

Answer (score 9):

If he eats meat, gets onto a fast plane and flies east, and lands before six hours have elapsed for him, I don't think anybody would say that he can now eat dairy just because the clock shows a later time.  For that matter, he doesn't get to jump the gun when switching to Daylight Saving Time.  (But citation needed.)  I would expect the same logic to apply to actual time dilation -- until it's been six hours (or whatever his custom is) *for him*, it doesn't count.

Comment: What about the situation I give in the comments above where 6 hours passes for him before it does for another observer?

Comment: @Daniel, I think that reverses.  If we're in a video conference and you see me eat, and then I get on a plane and fly west, and then you see me eat meat when the clock says it's only five hours later, you know -- because of context -- that I'm not doing anything wrong.  If we live in a world where time-dilation is routine, then the observer knows that that could have happened, right?

Comment: I think that's probably right. As a side note, I dont think your example is completely analogous because if you cross time zones, 6 hours have not actually passed, the clock just says 6 hours later. In my example, 6 hours have *actually* passed

Comment: although the same point may apply

Comment: But in the case of time dilation, it appears to me that 6 hours elapsed on earth at the same time that 6 hours elapsed for him, just that he doesn't feel as if 6 hours elapsed

Comment: @Daniel, ba makes a good point.  As soon as you have multiple observers, you never really know what time it is or how much time has elapsed.  But CYLPhysicist if this is a practical matter for you. :-)

Comment: @ba It's not that he doesn't *feel* as if 6 hours have elapsed. From his perspective, 6 hours *has not* elapsed, although you are correct that from the Earth's perspective, 6 hours has elapsed for him. @ MonicaCellio that's because how much time has elapsed is not an absolute fact. It depends on reference frame.

Answer (score 4):

According to the *P'ri Chadash* (89:6), six hours is not meant literally, and a person should just wait from one meal until the time for the next meal. In the winter, the *P'ri Chadash* writes, this could be approximately four hours. (Disclaimer: I haven't noticed many people follow this opinion in practice).

It seems reasonable to interpret the *P'ri Chadash* as understanding that you simply wait until the time for the next regularly scheduled meal. As such, let's say six hours passed on Earth (during the springtime, for example) and four hours passed for the astronaut. He might decide to eat at the scheduled meal time on Earth. Perhaps the *P'ri Chadash* would consider this acceptable.

A more immediate application of this question would perhaps involve an airplane trip from west to east (e.g. during spring). Let's say the flight is four hours and the destination is two time zones ahead the departure location. Perhaps the *P'ri Chadash* would allow the passenger to eat a dairy meal for supper in Chicago four hours after he ate a meat meal for lunch in Los Angeles.

Note also the reasoning given by the *P'ri Chadash* in 89:2, which suggests that there must still be a significant amount of time that elapses for the eater before he eats a dairy meal, so it is not possible to assume that the *P'ri Chadash* would permit any duration shorter than approximately four hours.

Comment: A novel interpretation and application, but I don't know anyone who does this.

Comment: @SethJ - An [example of someone who follows the *P'ri Chadash*](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11828/1442)?

Comment: Fred, first of all, without further confirmation from Hacham Gabriel, I don't see how that would necessarily follow. Second, I meant that I haven't ever heard of anyone eating based on what time zone he landed in. There's no relativity there, and even the P"Ch's logic doesn't lead in that direction. A traveler won't necessarily feel hungry at the time his hosts are eating, for example, if he just ate 4 hours ago.

Comment: @SethJ I didn't say that anyone does or should make that jump, but the theory seems reasonable. The P'ri Chadash (89:2) gives as the reasoning for waiting that meat particles in the mouth should have time to dislodge or dissolve. He does not suggest that it takes exactly six hours, and I doubt he meant that the time it takes varies by season. Rather, a vague range of timespans are included in the general rule to wait from one meal until the next. It is reasonable that a short day would have as much of an effect on the time until the next meal whether it was due to the season or a plane ride.

Comment: then why not just floss and help speed the process along?

Comment: @SethJ Read the P'ri Chadash. He says that "flossing" (well maybe not *exactly* flossing) alone isn't enough of a guarantee. As far as flossing and then splitting the difference timewise or something like that, I suppose לא נתנו חז"ל דבריהם לשיעורין.