# What if two communities had two different Shabbat days?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, calendar, communities

Imagine this: One community, A, keeps Shabbat on what we identify as Saturday. However, another community, B, for whatever reason, actually keeps Shabbat on what we identify as Sunday. These two different communities are keeping Shabbat in accordance with their mesora, but we obviously know one of the two communities must have failed in keeping track with the weekly calendar for whatever reason (let's just say a typhoon). What would be the halachic response for this discrepancy?

Comment: Is this assuming that these two communities are both isolated from the rest of the world but not from each other?

Comment: Rabbi Aivo (*P'sikta Rabbasi* 23) remarks that the positive command to remember Shabbos ("zachor") was given to seafarers, who don't know whether they are carrying in a permitted or prohibited manner. The *S'mag* (*Asin* 29) interprets this along the lines of [*Shabbos* 69b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=69b&format=text), that this refers to seafarers who don't know when Shabbos is. See also Shulchan Aruch ([OC 344](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%93%D7%9E)).

Comment: See also *Mishna B'rura* ([344](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%93%D7%9E)) who discusses the relative permissibility/prohibition of performing *m'lacha* on the designated Shabbos day and on the other six days.

Comment: You don't need to resort to an error in keeping track since near the international dateline there's a wide swath of areas that are subject to dispute amongst the achronim and the 2 communities could just follow differnt poskim.

Comment: In which case the halachik response shouldn't be any different than any other case of makom shenahagu - e.g. the community of rabbi eliezer who were mechalel shabbos for machshirei milah...

Comment: I think I recall hearing that this happened in [Kobe](http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v28/mj_v28i71.html#CVQ). cc @loewian

Comment: @loewian related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/322/halakhic-international-date-line-issues

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/implications-of-samoa-skipping-a-friday (Samoa now observes Shabbat on Sunday).