# Why is Saturday the Seventh Day?

Tags: shabbat

I was wondering, how does jews know that saturday was the seventh day since the beginning of the world?

Any references to prove that saturday is the seventh day. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Alyssa.  I think you may find your question has already been asked [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12868/how-do-we-know-that-the-civil-saturday-is-the-correct-shabbat?rq=1).