# Sabbath vs. Lunar Sabbath

Tags: shabbat

Wasn't the Sabbath based on the new moon indicating the start of a new month and the Sabbath accordingly was seven days later from its sighting in ancient times and not necessarily Saturday as we have from the Roman calendars?

Comment: No, you are confusing the months, determined by man, and the weeks, determined by G-d.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Jerry Kleintank, and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: Hi Jerry. Why would you think the Sabbath is counted from the new moon? Do you have any verses in Tanakh that suggest this? If so, please [edit] them into your question so we can better address your concerns.

Comment: As far as I can tell, lunar sabbath is a decidedly (minority) Christian concept, so I voted to close as not a comparative religion question. This question would be on topic if you took @DoubleAA's suggestion and instead asked why verse X Y or Z seems to indicate a lunar sabbath, but Judaism doesn't accept it as such.

Comment: As you can tell I am not of the the jewish faith but have been keeping the Sabbath for some time and recently read an article by John D. Keyser "biblical Proof of the Lunar Sabbath" which logically made sense to me. I am still puzzled as to if this is true how did we get to the Civil Sabbaths we keep today. It appears that Philo and Josephus in their commentaries agree also that this was the Sabbath used based on the new Moon and I thought whom better to ask then Mi Yodeya for a qualified answer. The article link is www.hope-of-israel.org/lunarsab.html I want to worship Yahweh as he commanded.

Comment: The Babylonians used such calendar. I didn't find any hint of a dispute on this conflict which leaves it open whether (less likely) the Jews adapted without discussion or (more likely) never even considered to adapt.

Answer (score 4):

The counting of the sabbath cycle (days) is not a lunar based one. Here is an excerpt from http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1103696/jewish/How-Do-We-Know-Which-Day-is-Shabbat.htm :

> We were first commanded to keep Shabbat in the desert shortly after we left Egypt. How did we know when to keep it? In Exodus 16, we are told that during our journey in the desert, manna fell every day except for one—the Shabbat. So what did we eat then? A double portion fell every Friday so that we would have what to eat the next day as well. On the first Friday after the manna began to fall, the people were surprised to see so much manna—double that which they had received on each of the past five days. When they came to ask Moses about this phenomenon, he revealed that the next day would be the Shabbat and that no manna would fall at all.

For more info, check out this question.
[How do we know that the civil Saturday is the correct Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12868/how-do-we-know-that-the-civil-saturday-is-the-correct-shabbat)

Comment: Sidebar to add - Sabbath is the only holy time set by G-d, and is a testimony to creation, itself. The New Moon and all holidays are set by Israel (via witness testimony in collaboration with Sanhedrin.) In the holiday Amidah, when Sabbath and the holiday coincide, the end of the "middle" blessing is ordered, :Who sanctifies the Sabbath, Israel and the holidays." Sabbath is first, b/c that's G-d's "call", THEN Israel is mentioned because they sanctify the holidays.