# Flying on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, halacha-theory

Would I be able to get on a direct flight that leaves Friday afternoon and lands on Motzei Shabbos?

How would this be different from getting on a boat before Shabbos and getting off the boat at your destination after Shabbos?

Please assume in answering this question that on the plane, I would not violate Shabbos (ex. turning on lights etc.).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Am I allowed to fly from Australia on Motzei Shabbos?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10806/am-i-allowed-to-fly-from-australia-on-motzei-shabbos)

Comment: see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10827/732

Comment: This question can probably be generalized to any form of public transit where you are not personally doing any Melacha. Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12331/riding-the-subway-on-shabbat

Answer (score 1):

Your questions are answered in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch [Siman 74](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0073_L2) - which refers to the boat traveling your mentioned in your question.

You would be only be permitted to travel if it were for a Mitzva - and the plane was not carrying only Jews.

(Practically speaking, you would have a lot of trouble with your assumption of being able to not violate Sabbat - from going to the washroom to even washing your hands for HaMotzi.)

Comment: Doesn't it actually say thats because seasickness will ruin your oneg shabbos? There is no seasickness here. And your ears popping are only momentary. You could argue from this that if your in economy it'll ruin your oneg shabbos. But buisness class and especially first class should be fine in regards to oneg shabbos. Also note that it says over there that some authorities hold its allowed for buisness as well.

Comment: @Orion - where did I or the Kitzur mention Sea-sickness?

Comment: your link wasn't working before so I went to sefaria. Actually it's the rif on shulchan aruch 248:2 which it quotes to explain it. Why do you think it says 3 days? The other peice about buisness is quoted from Rama 248:4 and mishna berura. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.74%3Flang%3Dbi&ved=2ahUKEwio06T3kLjdAhVLmlkKHQ7gDnAQFjAAegQIABAB&usg=AOvVaw3MmSik0BoJAKBPzwfOM_5A

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The question states that we assume you don't violate Shabbat. Could you sit in your seat all the flight and not go to the toilet... Is walking considered Assur more than 4 amot etc. Being "practically" difficult is not the same as Assur.